# Fancybox Get id of clicked anchor/element in afterClose function

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using fancybox for a login form. On successful validation, I am executing some code and closing fancybox manually within the `afterClose` callback.

The problem is that, if close fancybox using the close button `[X]`, my code inside the `afterClose` method still runs. How do I detect if I closed fancybox using the close `[X]` button? or how can I trace the current `click`? so  I can decide whether to run my code or not.

I have tried some tricks but still doesn't work.

Comment: what do you want to do with the `id` of the clicked element? and try reading here, there are method's for what you need http://fancybox.net/api

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the fancybox (v2.x) close button doesn't have an `ID`, it has *classes* only, however you can bind a `click` event to the `[X]` button and set your condition if the `[X]` close button was pressed or not.

Try catching in a variable the `currentTarget` of the `click` event like :

```
var eTarget;
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        afterShow: function () {
            // bind a click event to fancybox close button
            // set the value of the currentTarget to the eTarget variable
            eTarget=""; // reset variable
            $(".fancybox-close").on("click", function (event) {
                eTarget = event.currentTarget;
            });
        },
        afterClose: function () {
            // validate the eTarget variable 
            if ($(eTarget).hasClass("fancybox-close")) {
                // yes, we are closing fancybox with the [X] button
                // so close it, do nothing and return
                console.log("fancybox was closed using the X button");
                return;
            }
            // only if fancybox wasn't close using the X button
            // executed my validation and manual close
            console.log("perform form submission and validation here")
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DRVb6/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
console.log(this.element.context.id);
```